# How can I hide the insert status in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to hide

```
-- INSERT --
```

from the status line.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the command line mode type below line and press Enter

> :set noshowmode

And if you want to make it permanent then write that line (set noshowmode) without colon inside .vimrc file inside your home directory

Comment: Without the colon.

Comment: Commands in the .vimrc (or, indeed, Vim scripts in general) can have the colon in them, it just happens to be optional and most script writers prefer to exclude it.

Comment: I was having problem with this setting inside `.vimrc`, but not using `:set noshowmode`. To solve it, I had to put it at the bottom of my `.vimrc` file.